# How do I add a button to my navigationController's right side after pushing another view controller in?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

So, immediately after pushing a view controller to my tableView,

```
// Override to support row selection in the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  // Navigation logic may go here --
  //   for example, create and push another view controller.
  AnotherViewController *anotherViewController = 
      [[AnotherViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AnotherView" bundle:nil];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];
```

Ok, so that makes another view slide on, and you can go back to the previous view ("pop" the current view) by clicking the button that *automatically* appears in the top left corner of the navigation bar now.

Ok, so SAY I want to populate the RIGHT SIDE of the navigation bar with a DONE button, like in the "Notes" app that comes with the iPhone.  How would I do that?

I tried code like this:

```
  UIBarButtonItem * doneButton =
  [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
   initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
   target:self
   action:@selector( doneFunc ) ];

  self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton ; // not it..

  [doneButton release] ;
```

doneFunc is defined, and everything, just the button never appears on the right side..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

AH.  You have to do:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  AnotherViewController *anotherViewController = 
      [[AnotherViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AnotherView" bundle:nil];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];


  UIBarButtonItem * doneButton =
  [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
   initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
   target:self
   action:@selector( doneFunc ) ];

  anotherViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton ;

  [doneButton release] ;
}
```

Who'da thunk it.

Comment: You should have accepted Thomas' answer rather than your own.

Answer (score 32):

The code you posted should work fine, I think. Question is, where did you put it? I would put it into the `-viewDidLoad` method of the view controller you're pushing in. If you need different buttons depending on the content you're showing then you could do it in the `-viewWillAppear:` method.

**Update**: Actually, I think you need to change

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton;
```

to

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton;
```

Comment: No, tried that.. but it was helpful.  I moved it to viewDidAppear.  It seems the problem is the right button gets _HIDDEN_ whenever a new view controller is pushed on top of the stack

Comment: I've updated my answer. I think there is a bug in your code. Let me know if this fixes it.

Comment: No, I did try that, but the rightBarButtonItem still __disappears__ once the new view controller is pushed on.

Comment: You have to do all that in the *new* view controller, the one that you're pushing in.

Comment: Every view controller has an associated navigation item. This is what is displayed in a navigation bar. So it's the current view controller's navigation item that you want to manipulate. If you manipulated the navigation controller's navigation item then that would show if the navigation controller (also a view controller) were itself shown inside another navigation controller.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905618/self-navigationitem-rightbarbuttonitem-vs-self-navigationcontroller-navigationit